# MVC Themes, Layouts and CSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating an MVC application that will effectively allow a user to upload a number of **Themes** to the site.
Each **theme** they upload will have a **_Layout.cshtml** file, along with css files and images.
These will all be stored in locations mapped to the userId of the person creating the uploads, i.e.:

1. Users/Themes/32-bit-guid/_Layout.cshtml
2. Users/Themes/32-bit-guid/css
3. Users/Themes/32-bit-guid/images

The problem I have, is that although the templates are uploaded and I can select any of the templates (which are then applied to the current logged in user), the CSS files are ignored, along with the images.
If I try to browse to the path **Users/Themes/32-bit-guid/css/screen.css** which I know exists, I get a **resource cannot be found** error.

I have had a look at creating custom view engines, ignoring routes and everything, but I am getting no where.
Has anyone experienced this before and can they point me in the right direction please?

Comment: An update to this, I have found the issue is to do with code generated folders.
When I create a folder manually and copy the items into it, everything works perfectly.....

Comment: Well, after hours and hours of playing, I finally figured out it was simply to do with the web.config file I had in the folder.
Removing all the guff and just having the references to the DLL's needed for MVC fixed the issue I was having.
Now it all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views in MVC require a Web.config, all I did to get the themes working was copy the default web.config file from any Views folder and put it in the same directory as my Layout.cshtml